# PreparedStatement's setInt() not working on PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 with Tomcat 7 on Eclipse. The connection is made through a connection pool. When I use the `setInt()` method for the `PreparedStatement`, nothing is returned. When printing the prepared statement, the '?' is replaced by some weird String I suppose is a reference to the object. When I use the method `setObject()` with the appropriate `Type.INTEGER`, the printed statement contains the correct value, but as a String, and forcefully an Int is required.

Here's the code:

```
public User_DTO[] select(User_DTO params, int order, int limit, int offset)
{
    User_DTO result = null;
    ArrayList<User_DTO> result_arr = new ArrayList<User_DTO>(0);

    String query = "SELECT id, name, role FROM Usuario WHERE name LIKE ? AND role LIKE ? AND id != ? ORDER BY ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";

    String name = params.getName();
    String role = params.getRole();
    String id = params.getId();

    try
    {
        conn = Pool.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    
        stmt.setString(1, "%" + name + "%");
        stmt.setString(2, "%" + role + "%");
        stmt.setString(3, id);

                // Using setInt()
                // stmt.setInt(4, order);

                // Using setObject
        stmt.setObject(4, order, Types.INTEGER);
        System.out.println(order);
    
        if(limit == -1)
        {
            stmt.setNull(5, Types.NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            stmt.setInt(5, limit);
        }
    
        stmt.setInt(6, offset);

        //
        System.out.println(stmt);
    
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    
        while(rs.next())
        {
            result = new User_DTO();
        
            result.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            result.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            result.setRole(rs.getString("role"));
        
            result_arr.add(result);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sql_e)
    {
        sql_e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        Pool.close(conn, stmt, rs);
    }

    return (result != null) ? result_arr.toArray(new User_DTO[result_arr.size()]) : null;
}
```

The printed statement using `setInt()` is this:

```
SELECT id, name, role FROM Usuario WHERE name LIKE '%%' AND role LIKE '%%' AND id != '13253cc9' ORDER BY '[B@65adcbab' LIMIT '[B@75167bb3' OFFSET '[B@171360d3'
```

And the one printed using `setObject()`:

```
SELECT id, name, role FROM Usuario WHERE name LIKE '%%' AND role LIKE '%%' AND id != '13253cc9' ORDER BY '1' LIMIT '[B@75167bb3' OFFSET '[B@171360d3'
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: seems it treats to those params as array of bytes

Comment: can you log the query params before the query?

Comment: as far as I know, you should not expect a readable sql statement as the result of Statement.toString() (which is what you get when you do System.out.println(stmt). The question is - does the sql statement do what's intended? If so, then don't worry about it.

Comment: In the end, the problem was somewhere else, but as I could log the params correctly, got the Strings right in the printed Statement, and found nothing about what GreyBeardedGeek mentioned about Statements being non-readable, I thought there was something wrong there. Thank you for your help and that info!

Comment: On another note, you should almost never instantiate a `ArrayList` with an inital capacity of `0`. Since you're given a `limit` here, use `limit` as the initial capacity for your `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

Two quick thoughts on this.

1. The string you are seeing is the Integer object converted to a string.
2. Why are you trying to order the result by an Integer?

I think you have the number of parameters wrong. You have to order by a field of the tables included in the query, therefore you should not be giving the 4th parameter as an integer. In fact, you should probably have a fixed ordering.

Comment: ordering by 1 means order by first field from resultset. Ansi sql permits such ordering

Comment: ha! Only been doing this for years. That's new to me.

Comment: As maks mentioned, I'm ordering through the index of the field.

Answer (score -1):

```
public User_DTO[] select(User_DTO params, int order, int limit, int offset)
{
    User_DTO result = null;
    ArrayList<User_DTO> result_arr = new ArrayList<User_DTO>(0);
    
    StringBuffer queryBuffer = new StringBuffer("SELECT id, name, role FROM Usuario WHERE name LIKE ");
    queryBuffer.append("%");
    queryBuffer.append(params.getName());
    queryBuffer.append("%");
    queryBuffer.append(" AND role LIKE ");
    queryBuffer.append("%");
    queryBuffer.append(params.getRole());
    queryBuffer.append("%");
    queryBuffer.append(" AND id != ");
    queryBuffer.append(params.getId());
    queryBuffer.append(" ORDER BY ");
    queryBuffer.append(order);

    if (limit != -1)
    {
        queryBuffer.append(" LIMIT ");
        queryBuffer.append(limit);
    }

    queryBuffer.append(" OFFSET ");
    queryBuffer.append(offset);
    
    try
    {
        conn = Pool.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryBuffer.toString());

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            result = new User_DTO();

            result.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            result.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            result.setRole(rs.getString("role"));

            result_arr.add(result);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sql_e)
    {
        sql_e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        Pool.close(conn, stmt, rs);
    }

    return (result != null) ? result_arr.toArray(new User_DTO[result_arr.size()]) : null;
}
```

Use `StringBuffer` instead of the `setInt` or `setString`

Comment: 1) This makes your application vulnerable to SQL-Injections 2) You should not instantiate a `ArrayList` with an initial capacity of `0` if youre likely to add at least one entry. It would be much better the use `limit` for the initial capacity here